# Creating temp file with extension in Go within TravisCI

Tags: go, travis-ci

I am working on testing an application of mine, for which I need to create temporary files with specific extensions. My goal is to create files in a temp directory that look similar to this `example123.ac.json`.

In order to do this I am using `ioutil.TempDir` and `ioutil.TempFile`.

[Here](https://github.com/JonathonGore/travisci-bug) is a small contrived example of what I am doing.

**main.go:**

```
package main

func main() {
}
```

**main_test.go:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func TestMain(t *testing.T) {
    dir, err := ioutil.TempDir("", "testing")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("unable to create temp directory for testing")
    }
    defer os.RemoveAll(dir)

    file, err := ioutil.TempFile(dir, "*.ac.json") // Create a temporary file with '.ac.json' extension
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("unable to create temporary file for testing")
    }

    fmt.Printf("created the following file: %v\n", file.Name())
}
```

When I run the tests locally on my Mac with `go test` the following is outputted from the `fmt.Printf` is

```
$ go test
created the following file: /var/folders/tj/1_mxwn350_d2c5r9b_2zgy7m0000gn/T/testing566832606/900756901.ac.json
PASS
ok      github.com/JonathonGore/travisci-bug    0.004s
```

So it works as expected but when I run it in TravisCI the following is outputted from the Printf statement:

`created the following file: /tmp/testing768620677/*.ac.json193187872`

For some reason it is using the literal asterisk inside TravisCI but not when running on my own computer.

[Here](https://travis-ci.org/JonathonGore/travisci-bug) is a link to the TravisCI logs if interested.

For completeness here is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: go
go:
  - "1.10"
```

Anyone have any idea what is going on here? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature of replacing the first asterisk with the random value was [added in Go 1.11](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.11#io/ioutil). It looks like you are using go 1.10 for your Travis CI runs so the asterisk won't be replaced.